# Mysql use query result in new query

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables one called points_log and one called leaderboard.

```
mysql> describe points_log;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| points  | int(11) | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| date    | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe leaderboard;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bucket    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| user_id   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| school_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT leaderboard.user_id FROM leaderboard where 
 leaderboard.bucket=(SELECT bucket FROM leaderboard WHERE leaderboard.user_id=$user_id) AND
 leaderboard.school_id = (SELECT school_id FROM leaderboard WHERE leaderboard.user_id=$user_id)
```

This will return one or more rows with user_id's that are in the bucket with $user_id passed in. What I want to do is take all of those user_id's and find run the following query

```
SELECT sum(points) FROM points_log WHERE user_id=$user_id AND 
date >= (SELECT subdate(curdate(), INTERVAL (weekday(now())) DAY))
```

The issue is this second query if not guaranteed to return something, so in the case that it doesn't return anything I want sum(points) to be 0. I also need to return the user_id,bucket, and sum(points) for each row.

Right now what I have is

```
SELECT leaderboard.user_id,sum(points_log.points) AS points, leaderboard.bucket
        FROM points_log LEFT JOIN leaderboard ON points_log.user_id = leaderboard.user_id
        WHERE points_log.DATE >= (SELECT subdate(curdate(), INTERVAL (weekday(now())) DAY))
        AND leaderboard.bucket=(SELECT bucket FROM leaderboard WHERE leaderboard.user_id=$user_id)
        AND leaderboard.school_id = (SELECT school_id FROM leaderboard WHERE leaderboard.user_id=$user_id)
        GROUP BY USER_ID ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC
```

The issue with this is that it only works when there is a value in points_log for that user. I'm unsure how to make it default to 0 if there is no value.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT leaderboard.user_id, COALESCE( sum(points_log.points), 0 )AS points, leaderboard.bucket 
FROM points_log RIGTH OUTER JOIN leaderboard ON points_log.user_id = leaderboard.user_id 
WHERE points_log.DATE >= (SELECT subdate(curdate(), INTERVAL (weekday(now())) DAY)) 
AND leaderboard.bucket=(SELECT bucket FROM leaderboard WHERE leaderboard.user_id=$user_id) 
AND leaderboard.school_id = (SELECT school_id FROM leaderboard WHERE leaderboard.user_id=$user_id) 
GROUP BY USER_ID ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC
```

Try this... note the [Outer Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-simplification.html) and the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function.